# Can't log in after apt upgrade

Tags: apt, update, login

I ran a `sudo apt upgrade`, rebooted, and now I can't log in.

The odd thing is this... when I provide known invalid credentials the login dialog reports 'Incorrect password' in a red block, like so:

[image]

... but when I enter my known correct credentials the dialog disappears entirely for a moment and then returns with the password field empty (no red block).

Unfortunately I didn't enable SSH on this one, and have been connecting solely via VNC (lesson learned).

FYI the RPi is local, on the same LAN—if that helps.

Am I out of luck? Will I have to reinstall from scratch? (I sure hope not.)

Comment: Have you tried to login to the terminal and confirm that you are still able to do so?

Comment: Putting a file into your /boot directory called ssh should cause the sshd to start (touch ssh if you have another linux box, or just create an empty text file). Of course, ssh will need a password also.

Comment: @crasic — When you say 'terminal,' are you referring to a bash terminal? Or to the RPi directly and without VNC?

Comment: @NomadMaker — Catch 21. I would have to be able to log in to create such a file in that location. No?

Comment: /boot is formated as a FAT32, so Windows or Mac should be able to read or write in the /boot partician.

Comment: @Milliways — Buster, I believe. RPi 3 or 3b, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @NomadMaker — Aha. Alas, however, I don't have a microSDC adapter. Rats.

Comment: @NomadMaker — OK, the local chop shop has one. Be back in 40 mins.

Comment: @NomadMaker — Hm, no workee. Windows can see the FAT32 partition, but the OS partition is likely ext4. Windows wants to format it, which I'm not going to let it do. (Too bad, Windows.) Next up: move my monitor/keyboard into the other room and try a direct login.

Comment: You only need to change the /boot which is readable by windows. If you now have a usb sd card gadget, you can burn a new os, boot your pi with that, and then make any modifications on the old card.

Comment: if "I don't have a microSDC adapter" then HOW  did you initially install your OS?

Comment: @Milliways — About two years ago, in a different galaxy far, far away 

Comment: @NomadMaker — OK, back to the shop...! BRB

Comment: @NomadMaker — I tossed in the towel. I'm now running a spankin' new arm64 install. I bit the bullet and decided it'd be easier to just reinstall my apps.

Comment: @NomadMaker — Thanks for the help. I'll be able to use these tips in the future.

Comment: @Milliways — Thanks for the help. I'll be able to use these tips in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can boot to a root shell and reset password See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123850/8697.

Upgrade SHOULD NOT change password; ideally you should backup BEFORE upgrade.

This requires that you modify cmdline.txt - which can be done on any computer (even a Pi with a fresh OS).

Comment: I don't think it changed my password. I think login is succeeding, but maybe the desktop is crashing or something. That's why the dialog doesn't report 'Incorrect password,' but instead disappears for a moment and then comes back.

Comment: I tried adding `init=/bin/sh` to the end of `cmdline.txt`, but it still boots to the credentials dialog. Perhaps my Windows text editor added `CR`s to the file, and Buster doesn't like that. I do know that my current config replaces `tab`s with `space`s on file save, so that might be mucking with things. To your knowledge, does `cmdline.txt` require any `tab`s?

Comment: "does cmdline.txt require any tab" - definitely NOT - not sure what it may do with them if present.